# Reverse part of string

Tags: sql, oracle

by using SQL function 'reverse', do we  reverse a particular part in a string without changing the remaining characters ..                               [i.e praCTIce to praITCce];

thank you for replying;

Comment: `reverse()` reverses the entire string.  If you want to reverse part of a string, then provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, but assume you want to reverse first 3 character long uppercase string occurence so you can use:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/4378/0)**

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 'praCTIce' AS col FROM dual
)
SELECT 
     col AS original,
     REPLACE(col,
             REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '[A-Z]{3}'),
             REVERSE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '[A-Z]{3}')))  AS result
FROM cte;
```

You just need to `REPLACE` one substring with reversed substring.

**Warning**

Keep in mind that provided solution is not general, it is just demo/clue how to tackle problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can enhance the REVERSE function using the SUBSTRING or REGEXP class functions. The single REVERSE just reverses entire string.